# ¿Cuál es el criterio para representar valores nulos en JSON?

Tags: json

Quiero saber si en este JSON:

```
            "salmos": [{
                "orden": "1",
                "antifona": "Han llegado los días de penitencia; expiemos nuestros pecados y salvaremos nuestras almas.",
                "ref": "Salmo 118, 17-24",
                "tema": "NULL",
                "intro": "NULL",
                "parte": "NULL",
                "salmo": "Haz bien a tu siervo: viviré_y cumpliré tus palabras;_ábreme los ojos y contemplaré_las maravillas de tu voluntad;_soy un forastero en la tierra:_no me ocultes tus promesas.§Mi alma se consume, deseando_continuamente tus mandamientos;_reprendes a los soberbios,_infelices los que se apartan de tus mandatos;_aleja de mí las afrentas y el desprecio,_porque observo tus preceptos.§Aunque los nobles se sientan a murmurar de mí,_tu siervo medita tus leyes;_tus preceptos son mi delicia,_tus decretos son mis consejeros."
            }, { ...
```

los valores que aparecen así: `"NULL"`, serían interpretados **como una cadena cuyo valor es `NULL`** o serían interpretados **como el valor `NULL` propiamente dicho**.

La duda me vino porque no sé si podría tener problemas al momento de recuperar cualquiera de esos valores, los cuales pueden ser una cadena válida, o una cadena vacía que quisiera representar como `NULL` para mayor seguridad.

Comment: Si tienes control sobre serialización y deserialización puede ser una opción tambien simplemente quitar las entradas que son nulas y al deserializar comprobar cuales son las entradas que faltan.

Comment: No entendí muy bien tu comentario @Tao. Yo necesito un objeto con todas sus claves/valores (aunque algunas sean nulas)... se trata de una parte del JSON que guarda un array de elementos que necesito presentar en una app dando formatos y agregando más contenido según cada valor tenga contenido o no. Crear un objeto que no sea uniforme creo que me complicaría el trabajo en este caso.

Comment: @A.Cedano la representación puede ser cualquiera en el json, pero eso implica agregar un valor que al final dentro de la aplicación no tiene "valor",  considera incluso no agregar esos valores para reducir el tamaño de tu archivo. Los objetos que use la aplicación simplemente no tendran valor en esos campos.

Comment: A ver si me puedo explicar mejor. Si en un objeto en JSON una clave no existe la puedes tratar como null. Por ejemplo en JavaScript si tratas de leer una clave de un objeto que no esta definida no hay un error, pero el valor `undefined`. Eso puede ser una manera tambien de guardar espacio en el JSON. Pero si te lo hace mas complicado y el espacio no importa deja los.

Comment: @Jorgesys se trata de un JSON algo complejo cuyos datos debo presentar en una App de Android. La cuestión es que entre los datos hay una parte que sería un array en el cual puede haber una cantidad variable de elementos y yo quiero presentar todos esos elementos en la App debidamente formateados sin preocuparme de cuántos sean. Además cada parte de esos elementos llevaría estilos, formatos, colores de letra, etc dependiendo de si tienen datos o no. A eso me refiero cuando digo que quiero un JSON uniforme...

Comment: ... quiero decir, Jorge y @Tao, que el problema es más complejo [hoy he hecho 4 preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/29967/a-cedano?tab=questions&sort=newest) sobre diferentes cosas para poder llegar a este punto. Actualmente el código hace lo que yo quiero. En Android yo mando esa parte del JSON a un método y él me devuelve todos los salmos que haya debidamente formateados. Si yo creo el JSON omitiendo las claves que sean nulas (teniendo en cuenta que los datos vienen de un `SELECT` en BD), veo más complicado hacer lo que pretendo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Te puedo comentar con ejemplo;

```js
    var json1 = '{}';
    var json2 = '{"myCount": null}';
    var json4 = '{"myString": ""}';
    var json5 = '{"myString": "null"}';
    
    console.log(JSON.parse(json1)); // {}
    console.log(JSON.parse(json2)); // {myCount: null}
    console.log(JSON.parse(json4)); // {myString: ""}
    console.log(JSON.parse(json5)); // {myString: "null"}
```

**JSON1 {} :** Retorna un objeto vacio.

**JSON2 {"myCount": null}:** Esta es la forma definitiva de representar nulos segun la documentacion oficial http://www.json.org/

**JSON4 :** Retorna un string vacio.

**JSON5 {"myString": "null"}:** Con este tendras una cadena literal que contiene NULL como string.

Esta info la obtuve hace un tiempo de este post en ingles: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120999/representing-null-in-json

Comment: Es justamente como lo indicas. En el `json5` de tu ejemplo el valor es interpretado como una cadena y no como un valor `null`.

Comment: @A. Cedano exacto, es mas bien un String.

Answer (score 5):

En la segunda edición del [borrador final para el estándar la sintaxis de JSON](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) (con fecha de Diciembre de 2017), en la sección 5 de Valores en JSON (página 10 en el PDF enlazado) se indica que (traducción mía):

> Un valor en JSON puede ser un objeto, un array, un número, una cadena de texto, `true`, `false`, o `null`.
>
> [image: Posibles valores en JSON]

Por lo tanto `null` (en minúscula) se permitiría como valor y sería lo más apropiado para definir los valores nulos en JSON.

---

En el caso expuesto en la pregunta, los valores no se interpretarán como `null` sino como la cadena de texto "NULL" lo cual podría dar problemas porque al ser una cadena no vacía se evaluará como `true` en un condicional mientras que el valor `null` evalúa como `false`, pudiendo generar comportamientos inesperados. Por ejemplo:

```js
var miJSON = {
  nulo: null,
  textoNULL: "NULL"
}

if (miJSON.nulo) {
  console.log("nulo");
}

if (miJSON.textoNULL) {
  console.log("textoNULL");
}
```

Comment: Gracias Alvaro. No entendí lo que dices al final. Yo estoy evaluando los valores en Java/Android con este ternario: `salmoTema = (salmoTema.equals("NULL")) ? "" : CSS_RED_A + CSS_SM_A + salmoTema + CSS_SM_Z + CSS_RED_Z + BRS;` y me está funcionando bien. En este caso la cadena `NULL` que se asigna cuando no hay nada en esa clave del JSON está bien controlada, no se asignará nada extraño en ella, sino `"NULL"` o el valor que deba tener.

Comment: @A.Cedano por como estás haciendo la comparación, no tendrás problemas. Si la comparación se hiciese simplemente para ver si el valor existe o no, los resultados serían diferentes. He puesto un ejemplo comparándolos para ilustrar la diferencia.

Comment: Es interesante el comportamiento que señalas, el cual como has demostrado puede ser determinante en el caso de tener que hacer evaluaciones en base a si el valor existe. Pero en mi contexto lo que yo evalúo es el contenido del valor, para asignarle a la variable otro tipo de contenido en caso de que no sea igual a la cadena `NULL`.

Comment: Hola @AlvaroMontoro ¿que opinas de lo que comento en mi respuesta, me gustaría saber de tu experiencia?

Comment: "de lo contrario se consideraría el nombre de una variable" esa parte no es correcta. El parser no aceptaria un token NULL nada más, no existen variables JSON

Comment: @Klaimmore Tienes razón, he quitado esa frase. Me refería a generar un objeto JavaScript con la misma notación de JSON, donde sí se permitiría el uso de variables. Pero efectivamente no es lo mismo.

Answer (score 5):

Mas que preocuparse como representar los valores en el .json en este caso sería como representarlos en la aplicación y que esta funcione correctamente al contener este tipo de valores.

Puedes agregar los valores como desees representarlos en tu .json, por ejemplo:

```
{"myValue": null}
{"myValue": "null"}
{"myValue": ""}
```

o simplemente no agregarlo, ya que **tu parser es el que se encargara de representar esos valores en los objetos que usará tu aplicación,** obviamente tienes que validar cuando no existen estos valores en el .json.

Por experiencia el mejor acercamiento para manejar este tipo de valores es no agregar valor o no agregar la propiedad cuando esta tenga un valor null, una de las razónes es:

- Reducir tamaño del archivo a descargar, ancho de banda, etc.

al no leer estas propiedades no tendrás que agregarlas al objeto:

- Estas propiedades de tus objetos por lo tanto tendrán un valor null, que sería un beneficio si tu cantidad de objetos a construir es considerable, por lo tanto tu aplicación no consumirá memoria innecesaria.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: He [comentado largamente en la pregunta (2 comentarios seguidos)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/140684/cuál-es-el-criterio-para-representar-valores-nulos-en-json#comment263001_140684)  antes de ver tu respuesta. Entiendo lo que dices y puede que tengas razón. Pero hay más factores que intervienen aquí, como por ejemplo que los datos vienen de una base de datos que hace una consulta uniendo varias tablas... Para este caso concreto yo necesito (al menos eso creo), un *ejemplar* completo de cada salmo para poder trabajarlos en la App de forma automática.